# why we use braces built-in-class.__init__([])

Tags: python, list, oop, inheritance, super

I am new to python programming.
I was reading an inheritance from built-in-classes and I saw code like this.

```
class Anotherlist(list):
    def __init__(self, a_name):
        list.__init__([])
        self.name = a_name
```

so my question is what is the function of brackets inside parenthesis?

```
list.__init__([])
```

Comment: It's an empty list being passed as an argument to the `list.__init__` function.

Comment: That is an empty `list` object, i.e. `[]`. This is totally pointless, it should pass `self`, so `list.__init__(self)`.

Comment: It should also be `super.__init__`

Comment: *we* who? Were did you copy that code from?

Answer (score 1):

The line `list.__init__([])` doesn't do anything useful.

Likely, it should have been `super().__init__()` which would be useful in building "cooperative multiple inheritance".  See ["Python's super() consider super"](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

For everyday programming, the line could be omitted entirely because *list.__init__* with an empty argument will just clear the list.

Comment: Well, `list.__init__` is a no-op if you call it on an empty list, with no additional arguments. `list.__init__` will clear any existing contents, and if you pass it another iterable, it'll add the elements of that iterable to the list, but none of that matters here.